# Google script to move audio ".wav" files from one folder to another

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

So I need to move audio files that are dumped via a submission form into more specific folders.  I have about 10 folders in all That I need to move them to.  Here's the ask...

1. Collect the Audio files from the submission folder
2. Sort them into their appropriate folders based on key words in the file name

Here's the code I have so far.

```js
function moveFiles(source, target) {
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('source');
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('target')
  var files = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(Mimetype);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    targetFolder.addFile(file);
    file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
  }
}
```

I do not know the Mimetype for audio/wav or if it is supported in google scripts.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can retrieve the files using the mimeType of ``audio/wav``. If the files doesn't have the mimeType, for example, how about retrieving using the extension of files? By the way, can I ask you about ``Sort them into their appropriate folders based on key words in the file name``?

Comment: Sure! Right now,  I have .wav files being submitted via a submission form on my sheet. When given to the office, we will be receiving 100s of audio files daily.  I set up sub folders in the submission form folder here's an example:

Funny Folder
Serious Folder
Angry Folder

We have a naming convention for the .wav files submitted which looks like this:  

Bobby_Funny_R.wav

I want the script to take any .wav file that has "Funny" in its file name and move it to its target folder of "Funny Folder" . if that helps clear it up.

Comment: There's also the idea that i could select a word in the file name like "Funny" .  and pull all files that contain "Funny" then move them to a specific folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand the relationship between your script and your reply. And also I couldn't understand about your issue. Can you update your question including the detail information? By this, it will help users think of about your issue.